# How to run a file with a .324 extension in RHEL?

Tags: redhat, watson-studio

I am currently running installing Watson Studio Local on RHEL 7.6 (on Power architecture). This is the first time I've done this, so I followed the instruction [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHGWL_1.2.3/local/install.html).

After I've downloaded the tar file, I unpacked the file and for a file with the following name `DSXL-Installer-Power.ppc64le.324`. Honestly, this is the first time I've encountered a file with an extension of '.324'.

I'm not sure on how exactly to run the installation. I've tried to run it like a `.sh` file by doing `./DSXL-Installer-Power.ppc64le.324`, but it says 'permission denied'. Then I tried adding 'sudo' at the start, but it says 'command not found'.

I was wondering if anybody could point out what I was missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you run the installation on X86 architecture or on Power architecture?

Comment: I think it's the Power. I tried to run `arch`, and it outputs `ppc64le`

Comment: check with command `file DSXL-Installer-Power.ppc64le.324` and if its shell script run it like: `bash DSXL-Installer-Power.ppc64le.324` or `chmod +x DSXL-Installer-Power.ppc64le.324; ./DSXL-Installer-Power.ppc64le.324` (the second will work if this is executable file in general)

Comment: I tried to run `file DSXL-Installer-Power.ppc64le.324` and it outputs `DSXL-Installer-Power.ppc64le.324: data`. When I tried to run 'bash DSXL-Installer-Power.ppc64le.324', It outputs `The installer cannot be executed from the / filesystem`. Not sure what is happening still since I put the file in a sub-directory of `/`.

Comment: Seems like you need specific installer for this file. Check again the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from Romeo Ninov in the comment was almost correct.

Just make sure to use `a+x` instead of `+x` when using `chmod`.